# prestashop 1.7 how to edit the "add product" page in backoffice

Tags: symfony, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am trying without any success, to edit the page in the subject, because I have added 7 more fields in the product table that I would like to manage in the backoffice.

I have seen that the 1.6 version of Prestoshop had a specific view for that page and that it was pretty simple to add fields to the form. As to the 1.7 I'm going literally crazy, because I cannot find any view that manages the "add product" page.

Any hint? I know that it could probably have something to do with the introduction of Symfony in Prestashop, but I don't get how.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Solution found here. Great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44861846/1873501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is related to the Symfony / Twig part, like Module admin controllers, so you have to take a look here :  /src/PrestaShopBundle/Form/Admin/Product

Best way to debug this part is to use debug mode on 1.7 with Symfony bar, you can track what is happening with Twig !

All bundles are stored in ./src/ like in a classic Symfony installation.

Edit : A better way to achieve things would actually to make a module (https://validator.prestashop.com/generator) with displayAdminProductsExtra hook !

Comment: Don't forget to flag the answer :)

Comment: Matt, I have open that file...but no success in finding what I was looking for. Do you have any rapid insight? I sum up the situation: I have 7 more fields in the DB, I want them to be show in the add product view in back office. As far as I have learned reading the file, there is no "rendering" of such things. Can you please address more specifically? Thank you very much

Comment: MAtt, thanks for you answer. I'll mark it as correct, but I have found something more specific about it. Your lead was indeed correct, but this one goes inside the matter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675696/add-field-in-product-prestashop-1-7

Comment: Thanks Matt for pointing that the betters solution is to create a module