# Presta 1.7 where is informations.tpl

Tags: prestashop, backend

In Prestashop 1.6, there was a file "directory/themes/default/template/controllers/products/informations.tpl". 
But in Prestashop 1.7, I am not able to figure out how to change products template on backend. Where is this file and how can I override it without changing the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's now related to Twig and Symfony so you have to take a look at /src/PrestaShopBundle/Form/Admin/Product folder to make changes.

Dunno if you can override the templates but you may find some more information on this Q&A (and comments below my answer) : [prestashop 1.7 how to edit the "add product" page in backoffice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911736/prestashop-1-7-how-to-edit-the-add-product-page-in-backoffice/44911888#44911888)