# prestashop 1.7 new field file product admin

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I would like to make a new field (Image upload) in prestashop 1.7 adminproduct and i save it into product table.

[image: New field file product]
there anybody can help me.
thanks for advance.

Comment: create a plugin using the DisplayAdminProductsExtra hook

Comment: you can see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44861846/926171