# How to add custom product fields to prestashop using a module and hooks

Tags: php, prestashop, e-commerce, prestashop-1.7

I need to add some fields to prestashop product (HSN code and one more). I am very new to prestashop and there is no guide to do the same with latest build 1.7.

I have followed answers made on stackoverflow and I am able to show the form fields but unable to save and validate the value.
Here is the code snippet I have used (I preferred this because it uses the hooks).

```
    use PrestaShopBundle\Form\Admin\Type\TranslateType;
    use PrestaShopBundle\Form\Admin\Type\FormattedTextareaType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
    public function hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra($params)
    {
        $productAdapter = $this->get('prestashop.adapter.data_provider.product');
        $product = $productAdapter->getProduct($params['id_product']);

        $formData = [
        'ebay_reference' => $product->ebay_reference,
        ];
        $formFactory = $this->get('form.factory');
        $form = $formFactory->createBuilder(FormType::class, $formData)
            ->add('ebay_reference', TranslateType::class, array(
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'Ebay reference',
                'locales' => Language::getLanguages(),
                'hideTabs' => true,
                'required' => false
            ))
        ->getForm()
        ;
        return $this->get('twig')->render(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'MyModule/views/display-admin-products-extra.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]) ;

    }
    public function hookActionAdminProductsControllerSaveBefore($params)
    {
        $productAdapter = $this->get('prestashop.adapter.data_provider.product');
        $product = $productAdapter->getProduct($_REQUEST['form']['id_product']);
        foreach(Language::getLanguages() as $language){
            $product->ebay_reference[ $language['id_lang'] ] = 
                $_REQUEST['form']['ebay_reference'][$language['id_lang']];
        }
        $product->save();

    }
```

I am stucked at data saving part. Need some guidance to it in recommended way. Also need the suggestion to read the code of any module bundled with prestashop to help in this.

[Add field in product Prestashop 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675696/add-field-in-product-prestashop-1-7)

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code just describes how to create a form with necessary fields but it doesn't handle product class extending. So if you would have this attribute(ebay_reference) with all relations in your product class everything would work. So I suppose that you need to implement steps for `/classes/Product.php` and for `src/PrestaShopBundle/Model/Product/AdminModelAdapter.php` from the original answer of here [Add field in product Prestashop 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675696/add-field-in-product-prestashop-1-7) and add necessary field to the DB.

Also, if you don't want to modify or override default product class, you can create own table(s) to keep your data there like with id_product key, but it could be more difficult to propagate that data to all product instances in the store.